# How to achieve this effect? Motion effects similar to music speakers？

Tags: html, css, vue.js

[image: car]

I tried to use `CSS` to achieve it, but it did not achieve the expected effect, I want to achieve an effect similar to a car horn, the ring spreads outward from the center to achieve the style and effect as in the picture

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Uniform Expanding Circles</title>
<style>
  body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }

  .container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }

  .circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 2px solid #4FA6B5;
    animation-name: expand;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }

  @keyframes expand {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(2);
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="container"></div>

<script>

  const container = document.getElementById("container");

  function createCircle(numberOfCircles, i) {
    const circle = document.createElement("div");
    circle.classList.add("circle");
    
    const totalDuration = 2;
    const animationDuration = totalDuration;
    
    const delay = totalDuration / numberOfCircles * (numberOfCircles - i);
    
    circle.style.animationDuration = `${animationDuration}s`;
    circle.style.animationDelay = `${delay}s`;

    container.appendChild(circle);
  }

  const numberOfCircles = 6;

  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfCircles; i++) {
    createCircle(numberOfCircles, i);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the effect I achieved myself, but it doesn’t meet the requirements in the picture.

Comment: please share some code (by editing the question) which people can reproduce on their end, so that they can help you better

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the same result as the code you submitted, but using pure CSS? I tried your code and it looks good to me. Please make it super-clear what the requirements are. Thanks!